# Apache2 - Proxy or Redirect - What is "best practice"?

Tags: networking, apache2

I am about to set up a Ubuntu Server 16.04 that will be used different things. An example would be Plex Media Server, MySQL and Shibboleth-IDP and I am wondering what the best way is to set up Apache2, which I am using as front-end web server.

Today I have an adress (myaddress.example.net) that takes my to the default start page of Apache2. What I would like to achieve is that if I go to myaddress.example.net/pms (instead of adress:34597) or myaddress.example.net/idp (instead of adress:8080) I end up at each service.

My network setup is a classic home network. ISP (IP-address) -> Router -> Server / Computer (192.168.1.200). All http trafic (port 80) are forwarded to this server / computer (192.168.1.200).

Is mod_proxy, mod_redirect or any other way the best (practice) way to go?

Thank you in advance and best regards
Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About `mod_proxy` and `mod_alias`**

As Gumbo said on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917335/2069348) *`mod_redirect` does not exist, `Redirect` is a keyword from `mod_alias`*.

*Redirection* is used when the requested URL is somewhere else, and the browser itself will connect to the other server.

*Proxying* is used when the requested URL is somewhere else, but the server will do the connection. In this case the browser will even not be aware of that.

**About your situation**

Since you want to have access to have access to some applications from the outside of your local network, *proxying* is more appropriate, so you don't have to open and forward multiple ports from the outside.

**Best practice**

- **Don't use `http` without encryption**. You don't want to send your password sent unencrypted over the internet. If are not familiar with SSL,TLS and certificates, you should have a look at [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/).
- Even when using `https`, enable some authentication, either in Apache, either in your proxied application (You don't want some stranger to delete your files or mess with your configuration).

**Example**

For accessing your Plex Media Server myaddress.example.net/pms, you can add the following lines to `sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`:

```
ProxyPass         /pms  http://localhost:34597
ProxyPassReverse  /pms  http://localhost:34597
```